auto fill affecting react state
I have this react application, in the login form. if I use mobile view and the details auto fill, as I click the auto fill submit button, the signup section will appear instead. and this sign up is supposed to appear only if I clicked the don't have account, sign up here button. but it's like the auto fill submit button changes the state by calling this function below:
which is part of my code. how can I handle this?
I don't even know where to start.

const viewSignupForm = () => {
setShowWelcome(false);
setWelcomePic(false);
setShowLoginForm(false);
setConstructionPic(true);
setShowSignupForm(true)
setShowfpassword(false)
}

after some troubleshooting, i found out that the the auto fill submit button was triggering the first button of the form which in this case was the signup button. but because i didnt specify the type, auto fill read it as a submit button for the form, and being the first button found, it triggered it. i just specified the type to button and the issue was resolved, auto fill submit button ignored it and called the actuall submission button for the form there by triggering the loggin
